# creating multiple scenes in blender

Tags: rendering, animation

ok so i have an animation, ive made the first scene and ive rendered it, i then want to make another scene where i move the characters and the camera around, is there a way i can save the first scene so if i have to go back and edit anything im able to just open the scene and do what i gotta do?

Essentially im asking if i can save my scene, change it around and then be able to go back to the way the scene was before i changed it so i can render it again?

Comment: If you create a new scene, type > Full Copy type, the first scene and the new one won't be linked, which will allow you to make the changes you want without affecting the other one. This is an advantage and a disadvantage, depending on what you want. For example if you edit an object A in scene 1, its copy object B in scene 2 won't be changed. If you want it to be changed you'd better make some linked-duplicate objects...